# Bad keyword in scipy.stats.gaussian_kde?

Tags: python, scipy

The documentation on [scipy.stats.gaussian_kde](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) says that the keyword `bw_method` should be used to try different methods but when I try to use it I get an error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bw_method'
```

I'm running version `0.9.0` of `Scipy`, here's a `MWE`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import scipy

print scipy.__version__

## Generate some random two-dimensional data:
def measure(n):
    m1 = np.random.normal(size=n)
    m2 = np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=n)
    return m1+m2, m1-m2

m1, m2 = measure(2000)
xmin = m1.min()
xmax = m1.max()
ymin = m2.min()
ymax = m2.max()

# Perform a kernel density estimate on the data:
x, y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
positions = np.vstack([x.ravel(), y.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([m1, m2])
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values, bw_method='silverman')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround for scipy versions (before 0.12.0?) that do not have the `bw_method` keyword:

```
density = kde.gaussian_kde(data)
density.covariance_factor = density.silverman_factor
density._compute_covariance()
```

Inspiration for this workaround comes from [looking at the source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.12.0/scipy/stats/kde.py#L487).

---

This shows that the workaround above produces the same result as `kde.gaussian_kde(data, bw_method='silverman')`:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

data = ([1.5] * 7 + [2.5] * 2 + [3.5] * 8
        + [4.5] * 3 + [5.5] * 1 + [6.5] * 8)
x = np.linspace(0., 8, 100)

density = stats.gaussian_kde(data)
density.covariance_factor = density.silverman_factor
density._compute_covariance()
workaround = density(x)

density = stats.gaussian_kde(data, bw_method='silverman')
answer = density(x)

assert np.allclose(workaround, answer)
```

---

The `bw_method` keyword was added some time after version 0.9.0:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.__version__
'0.9.0'
>>> import scipy.stats.kde as kde
>>> density = kde.gaussian_kde(data, bw_method='silverman')
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bw_method'
```

Comment: Thank you for also providing a workaround unutbu, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested the result, but from the docs it appears that there's a method called silverman_factor(self):

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import scipy

print scipy.__version__

## Generate some random two-dimensional data:
def measure(n):
    m1 = np.random.normal(size=n)
    m2 = np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=n)
    return m1+m2, m1-m2

m1, m2 = measure(2000)
xmin = m1.min()
xmax = m1.max()
ymin = m2.min()
ymax = m2.max()

# Perform a kernel density estimate on the data:
x, y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
positions = np.vstack([x.ravel(), y.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([m1, m2])
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)
kernel.silverman_factor()
```